# Displaying data from two different data sets, one of which is null

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, lookup, isnull

I am attempting to display data from a table that populates it's column from an outside table.  My challenge is the "default" value does not exist in the table being referenced, so when referencing the outside record, any "default" unit is ignored.  I will try explain with pictures, the data sets I am looking at See image 1.

[image: Data set]

This is the data I am trying to display.  My problem child is the `UNITSNBR` column.  This data is pulling from a data table called `UNITS`.  See image 2

[image: UNITS Table]

The bridge I must cross is the default unit of measure when adding a part which is EACH.  This produces a "0" in the `Parts` data table, but there is no corresponding "0" in the `UNITS` table.  Any attempt to display `{UNITSNBR.DESCRIPTION}` breaks the report as there is not Description corresponding to 0.  I have had a small success with the following code Image 3

[image: Crystal code]

This produces the following results.  The challenge is I don't need to see `{PARTS.UNITSNBR}` as text, I need to see `{UNITSNBR.DESCRIPTION}` but it is not part of the `PARTS` data set and the default "0" is not part of the UNITS data set.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  If I need to be more clear, I will do my best to explain.

[image: Report output]

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I am very new to this entire Crystal world, if you are asking if I can write a query, then the answer would be no.  If that is what I need to learn, but need to post that as a separate question, I can.

Comment: Ah, no I do not have access to alter the data tables in any way.  The table in the fist screen shot is an Excel export of the schema data from the program.

Comment: I can accomplish the level of reporting visibility I need to in Excel, but it requires multiple exports and several Vlooks to get done and is not dynamic.  I am trying to replicate that in Crystal for the dynamic benefits.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if({PARTS.UNITSNBR}) = 0 then
  "EACH"
else
  {UNITS.DESCRIPTION}
```

Comment: That is one of the first things I tried in hopes this would be an easy fix, but it reduces my result from 6 pages of results to a single page of results.  I first tried this in records formula and also have tried it as a formula field that is inserted into the report.  Either way, I see 85% of my results disappear.

Comment: The only successful way(s) I have been able to display all results is to have the Field {UNITSNBR} displayed in the report (which gives numeric data, not description) or to use the snippet of code I shared in the post (which results in EACH and the numeric value of {PARTS.UNITSNBR} displayed as text.

Comment: The info in your question is not enough to see why you're getting less results, but try to use my answer for the formula in UOM and add the field `{UNITSNBR}` as a hidden column.

Comment: Is there a way to add images to comments?  I would like to be able to show you what I am doing and the results it is generating.

Comment: I have been able to accomplish the end goal by using multiple "else if" statements to account for the 30 some variable in the {UNITSNBR} table, but I would be very curious if there is a better solution.  As it sits, the report would have to be edited any time a Unit of Measure is added or edited.  I would very much prefer a more dynamic solution.

Comment: No there is no way to add images to the comments. You'll need to edit your question and add the images there.

Comment: Are you sure that every `{PARTS.UNITSNBR}` value in your 6 pages of results has a corresponding `{UNITS.DESCRIPTION}`? It seems that some values don't have a description and so you will need to add a record for them or you have to add an exception for them in your formula like you did with the zero. I see in your first screenshot `UNITSNBR` value of 75, do you have that many records in the `UNITS` table?

Comment: Also note that in your question you typed `{UNITSNBR.DESCRIPTION}` and I copied that to my answer, but I think that was a typo and should be `{UNITS.DESCRIPTION}` instead. I've updated my answer.